# Databricks Delta Table Merge statement using R

Tags: r, databricks, delta-lake, sparklyr

I have recently started working on Databricks and I have been trying to find a way to perform a merge statement on a Delta table, though using an R api (preferably sparklyr). The ultimate purpose is to somehow impose a 'duplicate' constraint as described  [here](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#language-python). The aforementioned documentation describes the Python workflow :

```
deltaTable.alias("logs").merge(
    newDedupedLogs.alias("newDedupedLogs"),
    "logs.uniqueId = newDedupedLogs.uniqueId") \
  .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
  .execute()
```

however, I was wondering whether there is a straight-forward way to achieve this through R. Any assistance/ideas on the matter will be much appreciated since I am a new user (as mentioned above).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Providing this answer since the you commented that there is no R Delta Lake API support. There is now a new R package that provides an R API for Delta Lake: [dlt](https://dlt.zero323.net/#merging-sparkdataframe-with-deltatable). The syntax is very similar to that of the Python API for Delta Lake.

In the case of your example:

```r
# Install and laod the `dlt` package
remotes::install_gitlab("zero323/dlt")
library(dlt)
...

# Use the Delta Lake R API from the dlt package
deltaTable <- dlt_for_path("<path to table>")

deltaTable %>%
  dlt_alias("logs") %>%
  dlt_merge(alias(newDedupedLogs, "newDedupedLogs"), expr("newDedupedLogs.uniqueId = logs.uniqueId")) %>%
  dlt_when_not_matched_insert_all() %>%
  dlt_execute()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no official R API for Delta Lake, but you can just use SQL's [MERGE INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-merge-into) command for that (I often do it in Scala/Python, just because it's easier to read, at least for me).  You need to register a temp view with data that you want to put into destination table, and just run `sql`, like this (string is split for readability):

```r
library(SparkR)
updates_df <- ...get updates...
createOrReplaceTempView(updates, "updates")
result <- sql(
  "MERGE INTO <your_table> AS target USING updates 
   ON target.id = updates.id WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *")
```

Comment: That's sad, ref to no official support for R Delta Lake API support. Anyhow, thanks a lot for the solution and feedback provided ; any case I can avoid the TempView? I suppose not, correct?

Comment: You can theoretically write down to disk and use it, but it would be worse than temp view

Comment: Btw, it looks like some wrapper for R is released, although not official